# Adding new nodes to D3 Layout Partition on Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, d3.js, nodes

I am using the layout partition in D3 (v3). I have the code working well based off of the demo located here: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/partition.html

HOWEVER, I now want to add in code so that when a user clicks a node, if it does not have any children, it does an ajax call to get its children and loads them into the partition and then zooms in on that node, just like it does normally.

I have the code working to do the Ajax call and get the node's children, but I cannot figure out how to add them to the partition. I've done something similar for a D3 tree and did not have many issues getting it to work, but I can't figure it out for Partition.

My code is pretty much the same as the demo, except that on click, it does an Ajax call to get the children and then does:

```
var newnodes = partition.nodes(jsonObj[0].children).reverse();
d.children = newnodes[0];
update(d);
```

Here is the update method:

```
function update(d) {
    nodes = partition.nodes(root);

    kx = (d.y ? w - 40 : w) / (1 - d.y);
    ky = h / d.dx;
    x.domain([d.y, 1]).range([d.y ? 40 : 0, w]);
    y.domain([d.x, d.x + d.dx]);

    var t = g.transition()
        //.duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750) this just slows it down, which we don't care about
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x(d.y) + "," + y(d.x) + ")"; });

    t.select("rect")
        .attr("width", d.dy * kx)
        .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dx * ky; });

    t.select("text")
        .attr("transform", transform)
        .style("opacity", function(d) { return d.dx * ky > 12 ? 1 : 0; });
}
```

I am using jQuery to do the Ajax call and other coding, so I have it available, as well as D3.

Has anyone done this before? I am new to D3 and am still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, and the it looks like the nodes that come back from the Ajax call are added to the DOM, but they don't show up in the correct place. They are being put off-screen instead of to the right of the parent node.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's tough to abstract the code out to do a fiddle, but I'll try to do so.